MAUI CarouselView
I'm having trouble using CarouselView. Problem is that Images attached to each page gets changed over time when I keep swiping
<CarouselView
    x:Name="Carousel"
    Margin="0,25,0,0"
    IsVisible="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ParsedChapters}"
    Loop="False"
    PositionChanged="Carousel_PositionChanged">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Labels}" SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                </CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
                <CollectionView.Header>
                    <Image
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                        MaximumHeightRequest="200"
                        Source="{Binding Logo}" />
                </CollectionView.Header>
......

Data is  ObservableCollection of this DT
public class PageData
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Labels { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ImageSource? Image{ get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; } = false;
}

Bug :  for example current page is 1 and there is img1, I scroll to page n and there's imgN, after returning back to page 1 there's no longer img1 but some other imgM, seems like order is shuffled or something. This happens time to time, not always. Also if I keep scrolling in order, images are rendered correctly. Only images got this problem, not text
I've tried different ways to store ImageSource, like Streams, storing on disk and bind by path but still same bug

This may or may fix your problem, but, it is best practice to use compiled bindings by setting x:DataType wherever possible. For your specific problem, have you tried turning of the cache with CacheEnabled="False". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image?view=net-maui-8.0

Adding  did work.
Caching was disabled as i see in docs "mage caching is disabled on Android when loading an image from a stream ...".
Thanks for your attention

We can add the x:DataType property to DataTemplate,
just as follows:
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:PageData">

